# Get element by id written more simply?

Tags: javascript, html, css, getelementbyid

I was wondering, you know how we write `document.getElementById('id').innerHTML` etc. Can this line be written just as

```
('id').innerHTML
```

is it the same for `.value`?

Comment: See [Jquery](https://jquery.com/). And if there's something still simpler, let me know

Answer (score 1):

Well this is weird, but sure, why not!

I wouldn't really recommend actually doing this outside of small personal fun projects, but it's *technically possible*, you just need to extend the built-in `String` prototype with a getter/setter pair (so that you can call `innerHTML` on a string directly):

```
Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, "innerHTML", {
    get: function () {
        return document.getElementById(this.valueOf()).innerHTML;
    },
    set: function (value) {
        document.getElementById(this.valueOf()).innerHTML = value;
    }
});
```

And then you can simply do this:

```
("id").innerHTML = "element contents";
```

Which, BTW, is the same as:

```
"id".innerHTML = "element contents";
```

*(seriously, don't do this for real projects)*

Answer (score 0):

I might be stating the obvious, but you could always create a custom function..

```
function getCustomElementById(id) { return document.getElementById(id).innerHTML; }
```

so you can just call

```
var content = getCustomElementById("someid");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery it has more simplified it.

JS:

```
document.getElementById('id')
```

jQuery:

```
$('#id')
```

Answer (score 0):

With plain JavaScript you could just set it as a variable

```
var x = document.getElementById('id');

x.innerHTML = 'blah';
```

Or you could use jQuery :)

Answer (score -1):

Using [Jquery](https://jquery.com/) : `$('#id').html();` to get and `$('#id').html("value");` to set